# JSPDF shift to new page when Data is full in page

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am new in JSPDF and creating a page of PDF like this [image: Lable view of data] Now Problem is that when data is full on this page it didn't produce new page. I have that [github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/101) and other solutions on stack overflow. but not getting solution. 
[JSPDF demo link is here][3]

[3]: > https://jsfiddle.net/jodfkz59/7/

```js
var data = [{
      "Name": "Ronan",
      "Email": "sodales.elit@eratSed.co.uk",
      "Company": "Malesuada Malesuada Ltd"
    }, {
      "Name": "Calvin",
      "Email": "amet.nulla@Vestibulumante.ca",
      "Company": "Donec Egestas Foundation"
    }, {
      "Name": "Kane",
      "Email": "Duis.mi@consectetueradipiscingelit.net",
      "Company": "Arcu Institute"
    }, {
      "Name": "Kasper",
      "Email": "magna.Phasellus.dolor@velconvallisin.co.uk",
      "Company": "Tempor LLP"
    }];
    
    
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    //Dimension of A4 in pts: 595 × 842
    
    var pageWidth = 595;
    var pageHeight = 842;
    var y=500;
    var pageMargin = 10;
    
    pageWidth -= pageMargin * 2;
    pageHeight -= pageMargin * 2;
    
    var cellMargin = 5;
    var cellWidth = 250;
    var cellHeight = 60;
    
    var startX = pageMargin;
    var startY = pageMargin;
    
    function createCard(item) {
    
      // doc.getTextDimensions(item.Name); turncate or split string if you needed
      
    if (y >= pageHeight)
{
  doc.addPage();
  y = 0 // Restart height position
}
    
      doc.text(item.Name, startX, startY);
      doc.text(item.Email, startX, startY + 20);
      doc.text(item.Company, startX, startY + 40);
    
      var nextPosX = startX + cellWidth + cellMargin;
    
      if (nextPosX > pageWidth) {
        startX = pageMargin;
        startY += cellHeight;
      } else {
        startX = nextPosX;
      }
    
    }
    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      createCard(data[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You didn't confuse `y` and `startY`? In your code, y is always 500

Comment: @Fefux I was trying with diff values. If you have idea can you guide me please ?

Comment: See here : https://jsfiddle.net/jodfkz59/7 . I just change your condition to add pages

Comment: @Fefux I think you forget to update fiddle ? code is same . And no new page is added

Comment: sorry => https://jsfiddle.net/jodfkz59/8/

Comment: @Fefux thank you brother . Yes I needed this. Can you post this as your answer So that I will mark it as answer . thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the condition in the function `createCard`. You have to change your test on your real current value of y offset.

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jodfkz59/8/

```
var data = [{
      "Name": "Ronan",
      "Email": "sodales.elit@eratSed.co.uk",
      "Company": "Malesuada Malesuada Ltd"
    }, {
      "Name": "Calvin",
      "Email": "amet.nulla@Vestibulumante.ca",
      "Company": "Donec Egestas Foundation"
    }, {
      "Name": "Kane",
      "Email": "Duis.mi@consectetueradipiscingelit.net",
      "Company": "Arcu Institute"
    }, {
      "Name": "Kasper",
      "Email": "magna.Phasellus.dolor@velconvallisin.co.uk",
      "Company": "Tempor LLP"
    }];


    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    //Dimension of A4 in pts: 595 × 842

    var pageWidth = 595;
    var pageHeight = 842;
    var y=500;
    var pageMargin = 10;

    pageWidth -= pageMargin * 2;
    pageHeight -= pageMargin * 2;

    var cellMargin = 5;
    var cellWidth = 250;
    var cellHeight = 60;

    var startX = pageMargin;
    var startY = pageMargin;

    function createCard(item) {

      // doc.getTextDimensions(item.Name); turncate or split string if you needed

    if (startY >= pageHeight)
{
  doc.addPage();
  startY = pageMargin  // Restart height position
}

      doc.text(item.Name, startX, startY);
      doc.text(item.Email, startX, startY + 20);
      doc.text(item.Company, startX, startY + 40);

      var nextPosX = startX + cellWidth + cellMargin;

      if (nextPosX > pageWidth) {
        startX = pageMargin;
        startY += cellHeight;
      } else {
        startX = nextPosX;
      }

    }


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      createCard(data[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "startY" and add 1000, it will automatically push to new page

```
doc.autoTable({html:"#exportfrontpageTable",startY:doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + 1115});
```